# variable not passed to lower level?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand that variables in python are always (?) available in subfunctions.

That is why this works:

```
def abc():
    print(a)

def main():
    abc()
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    a = 'a'
    main()
```

However, why does it not work if the definition of `a`is moved to `main()`?

```
def abc():
    print(a)

def main():
    a = 'a'
    abc()
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

It is still defined before it is used and should be available in `abc()`, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Because then it is a **local** variable of `main`. Simple as that

Comment: @Tomerikoo: But why do I get a `shadows name from outer scope` warning in pyCharm every time I use the same variable name in a different function that is called by another function?

Comment: I don't know... must be some leftovers from different versions you're trying

Comment: Maybe it is only apparent in sub functions... I will have to look through my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, variables defined in a function are scoped to the function by default. To make it available in `abc()` you would need to make it `global`:

```
def main():
    global a
    a = 'a'
    abc()
```

As for the 'shadowing' warning, you get it when you redefine names at inner scopes.  For example, this code creates a *global* variable `a`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 'a'
    main()
```

Now if you do `a = 'b'` inside `main()` you are effectively 'shadowing' `a` from the outer scope by creating a local variable with the same name.

Comment: But why do I ge a `shadows name from outer scope` warning in pyCharm every time I use the same variable name in a sub function?

Comment: You can get such warning when you redefine a global variable (i.e. defined at the module level, like `a` in your first example) inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

In the first code sample, 'a' is defined as a global variable. Meaning that it can be accessed by any function called after it is instantiated.

In the second code sample, 'a' is defined as a local variable. Meaning that it only exists within the "main" function. If you wanted to pass it into the "abc" function, you would have to explicitly pass that variable. That would look like:

```
def abc(a):
   print(a)

def main():
   a = 'a'
   abc(a)
   pass

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables at the module level of your function are available *to read* anywhere else in the module. When you do

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    a = 'a'
```

you are defining a as a module-level variable, hence why you can read it inside `abc()`. This is similar to why you can see your imports within other functions.

When you define `a` inside `abc()`, it's no longer at the module-level and no longer is implicitly readable elsewhere in the module.

As an aside, global variables are usually a bad idea, it's better to pass them around explicitly. See http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad for a good summary of why.